# How to better correlate Spring Integration TCP Inbound and Outbound Adapters within the same application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I currently have a Spring Integration application which is utilizing a number of TCP inbound and outbound adapter combinations for message handling. All of these adapter combinations utilize the same single MessageEndpoint for request processing and the same single `MessagingGateway` for response sending.

The MessageEndpoint’s final output channel is a `DirectChannel` that is also the DefaultRequestChannel of the MessageGateway. This `DirectChannel` utilizes the default `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy` which is doing a Round Robin search for the correct Outbound Adapter to send the given response through. Of course, this round robin search does not always find the appropriate Outbound Adapter on first search and when it doesn’t it logs accordingly. Not only is this producing a large amount of unwanted logging but it also raises some performance concerns as I anticipate several hundred inbound/outbound adapter combinations existing at any given time.

I am wondering if there is a way in which I can more closely correlate the inbound and outbound adapters in a way that there is no need for the round robin processing and each response can be sent directly to the corresponding outbound adapter? Ideally, I would like this to be implemented in a way that the use of a single `MessageEndpoint` and single `MessageGateway` can be maintained.

**Note:** Please limit solutions to those which use the Inbound/Outbound Adapter combinations. The use of TcpInbound/TcpOutboundGateways is not possible for my implementation as I need to send multiple responses to a single request and, to my knowledge, this can only be done with the use of inbound/outbound adapters.

To add some clarity, below is a condensed version of the current implementation described. I have tried to clear out any unrelated code just to make things easier to read...

```
// Inbound/Outbound Adapter creation (part of a service that is used to dynamically create varying number of inbound/outbound adapter combinations)
public void configureAdapterCombination(int port) {

    TcpNioServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TcpNioServerConnectionFactory(port);
    // Connection Factory registered with Application Context bean factory (removed for readability)...

    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    inboundAdapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    inboundAdapter.setOutputChannel(context.getBean("sendFirstResponse", DirectChannel.class));
    // Inbound Adapter registered with Application Context bean factory (removed for readability)...

    TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    outboundAdapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    // Outbound Adapter registered with Application Context bean factory (removed for readability)...

    context.getBean("outboundResponse", DirectChannel.class).subscribe(outboundAdapter);

}

// Message Endpoint for processing requests
@MessageEndpoint
public class RequestProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private OutboundResponseGateway outboundResponseGateway;

    // Direct Channel which is using Round Robin lookup
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel outboundResponse() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Removed additional, unrelated, endpoints for readability...

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="sendFirstResponse", outputChannel="sendSecondResponse")
    public Message<String> sendFirstResponse(Message<String> message) {
        // Unrelated message processing/response generation excluded...
        outboundResponseGateway.sendOutboundResponse("First Response", message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, String.class));
        return message;
    }

    // Service Activator that puts second response on the request channel of the Message Gateway
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendSecondResponse", outputChannel="outboundResponse")
    public Message<String> processQuery(Message<String> message) {
        // Unrelated message processing/response generation excluded...
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Second Response").copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();
    }

}

// Messaging Gateway for sending responses
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="outboundResponse")
public interface OutboundResponseGateway {
    public void sendOutboundResponse(@Payload String payload, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) String connectionId);
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

@Artem's suggestions in the comments/answers below seem to do the trick. Just wanted to make a quick note about how I was able to add a `replyChannel` to each Outbound Adapter on creation.

What I did was create two maps that are being maintained by the application. The first map is populated whenever a new Inbound/Outbound adapter combination is created and it is a mapping of `ConnectionFactory` name  to `replyChannel` name. The second map is a map of `ConnectionId`  to `replyChannel` name and this is populated on any new [`TcpConnectionOpenEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpConnectionOpenEvent.html) via an `EventListener`.

*Note that every `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` will have a `ConnectionFactoryName` and `ConnectionId` property defined based on where/how the connection is established.*

From there, whenever a new request is received I use theses maps and the 'ip_connectionId' header on the [`Message`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message.html) to add a `replyChannel`  header to the Message. The first response is sent by manually grabbing the corresponding `replyChannel` (based on the value of the `replyChannel` header) from the application's context and sending the response on that channel. The second response is sent via Spring Integration using the `replyChannel` header on the message as Artem describes in his responses.

This solution was implemented as a quick proof of concept and is just something that worked for my current implementation. Including this to hopefully jumpstart other viewer's own implementations/solutions.

Comment: Please, share your configuration with us for better understanding what is going on.

Comment: @Artem is there something specific you want to see? I can update the original question to include what you need. Just want to make sure what I add is actually what you need.

Comment: Show me, please, at least one flow from start to the end. I don’t see the whole picture. Of course, would be great to see the project at all, but I guess it is not possible from your side...

Comment: This architecture sounds very bizarre. I agree that we need some configuration and some explanation of exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds strange that you use the same channel as an output and as a request one for gateway. Even though there still must not be round-robing on subscription to that channel unless you really have several of them.

Comment: @Artem I am going to add a condensed version of our implementation to the original question. If you and Gary could please take a look when possible. Hopefully this will provide some clarity.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see now your point about `round-robin`. You create many similar TCP channel adapters against the same channels. In this case it is indeed hard to distinguish one flow from another because you have a little control over those channels and their subscribers.

On of the solution would be grate with Spring Integration Java DSL and its dynamic flows: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

So, you would concentrate only on the flows and won't worry about runtime registration. But since you are not there and you deal just with plain Java & Annotations configuration, it is much harder for you to achieve a goal. But still...

You may be know that there is something like `replyChannel` header. It is taken into an account when we don't have a `outputChannel` configured. This way you would be able to have an isolated channel for each flow and the configuration would be really the same for all the flows.

So,

- I would create a new channel for each `configureAdapterCombination()` call.
- Propagate this one into that method for `replyChannel.subscribe(outboundAdapter);`
- Use this channel in the beginning of your particular flow to populate it into a `replyChannel` header.

This way your `processQuery()` service-activator should go without an `outputChannel`. It is going to be selected from the `replyChannel` header for a proper outbound channel adapter correlation.

You don't need a `@MessagingGateway` for such a scenario since we don't have a fixed `defaultRequestChannel` any more. In the `sendFirstResponse()` service method you just take a `replyChannel` header and send a newly created message manually. Technically it is exactly the same what you try to do with a mentioned `@MessagingGateway`.

For Java DSL variant I would go with a `filter` on the `PublishSubscribeChannel` to discard those messages which don't belong to the current flow. Anyway it is a different story.

Try to figure out how you can have a reply channel per flow when you configure particular `configureAdapterCombination()`.

Comment: This seems to make sense but I do have one initial concern... I understand how adding of the replyChannel header to the message would allow for us to specify the exact Outbound Adapter but  by removing the outputChannel prop from the service activator annotations are we not breaking the chain between the sendFirstResponse and processQuery service activators?

Comment: The `sendFirstResponse()` still has to have that `outputChannel="sendSecondResponse"`. The `processQuery()` will have `inputChannel = "sendSecondResponse"` to be subscribed to the output above. And only exactly this `processQuery()`  must not have `outputChannel` because we are going to deal with a `replyChannel` header only here to return a control from this common sub-flow to the particular TCP outbound channel adapter.

Comment: Can you clarify how the sendFirstResponse() method gets the first response to the appropriate TCP outbound channel adapter? Will the presences of an outputChannel and replyChannel allow for it to send it both the processQuery() service activator and the appropriate outbound adapter?

Comment: You still have to do that manually, but instead of using `@MessagingGateway`, you need to take a `replyChannel` from headers and send message to this one.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for the clarification. I agree with your initial concern that this is  getting a bit messy and will require some coordination to maintain correctly. Although I am brand new to Integration Flows, I am still interested in what this solution might look like using that approach. Do you have any relatable examples?

Comment: This sample has something relevant to your question: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client